# Error Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx8192m Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: java, presto, trino

I am new to Trino, i did the clone of the code source of Trino from github : https://github.com/trinodb/trino and I get this error :

Invalid maximum heap size: `-Xmx8192m`
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. The program will exit.

I tried these solutions on this site: https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/how-to-fix-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-error/ and it didn't work either
What is the problem and what should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Add the complete command line and all arguments used to start Java to the question. Is the error message complete? Please use code format and ensure all lines and format of the message is preserved.

Comment: Hi, please indicate the version of Java you are using and the command you are running when receiving the error you indicate.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you are assigning more memory to the heap than your system has available. Try with a smaller amount. If your JVM is 32-bits and your operating system is 64-bits you could try using a 64-bits JVM so it can handle more memory.